# How to allow rotate transform and layout transform work together

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple canvas as follows:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvBackground" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Background="Blue">
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransformBackground"
                            ScaleX="{Binding Value,
                                             ElementName=uiSliderZoom}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding Value,
                                             ElementName=uiSliderZoom}" />
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransformBackground"
                            Angle="{Binding Value,
                                             ElementName=uiSliderRotate}"></RotateTransform>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform  >
    </Canvas>
```

These transform are bound to two slider controls. I have assigned an imagebrush to the background of the canvas which works fine. At the time I assign the imagebrush I am setting the centerX and centerY properties of both transforms to half the X and Y of the image. The zoom slider works as expected as does the rotate slider.

When I combine the zoom and slider I'm getting odd results (i.e. the rotate transform is still based on the centerX and centerY properties of the original size image. Therefore the rotate and zoom do not behave as expected (zoom in to out and rotate around the centre of the image.

Can anyone assist?

Many thanks.

Comment: `LayoutTransform` gets applied during the Layout pass of the application, while `RenderTransform` gets applied during the Render cycle. Since they run at different times, be sure you're using the correct transform type for your operation so the transforms get applied at the right time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put both Transforms in a TransformGroup and assign that to either LayoutTransform or RenderTransform:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvBackground" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" Background="Blue">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransformBackground"
                            ScaleX="{Binding Value, ElementName=uiSliderZoom}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding Value, ElementName=uiSliderZoom}" />
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransformBackground"
                             Angle="{Binding Value, ElementName=uiSliderRotate}" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform  >
</Canvas>
```

And you may also need to set the [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks guys - I misunderstood the workings of transforms - that's helped alot - much appreciated.